# Your app is uploading users' Contact List and Images information to without posting a privacy policy in Play Distributed App

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm gettting the following error from playstore

[image]

> I have added these information in the privacy policy url

[image]

> And I have designed a popup screen on the app's dashboard itself

[image]

> And finally I have designed a popup before getting the permission

[image]

> **What else I need to do. Your help will will be highly helpful to me. Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the disclosures all in one dialog.
For example, as soon as your app wants to access the contacts, show a disclosure dialog that describes what you are collecting and for what purpose. When the user clicks "I agree", you request permission for the contacts. If the user clicks on "Decline", you leave it alone and the app has to do without contacts.
You do the same with the other permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would file a privacy statement with them.

It's about 20 questions ... if you're working for a company, somebody must deal with that kind of stuff professionally ... it would be whoever runs the play store account.